# C# удалить многострочный коментарий из визуального приложения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, визуализация, комментарии

Визуальное приложение имеет два текст бокса: в первый записывается текст из файла, во второй тот же текст без комментариев.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String i = "";
            richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("D:\\3.txt");
            this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sourceText = richTextBox1.Text;
            var firstPhaseText = Regex.Replace(sourceText, "[ ]+", " ");
            var secondPhaseText = Regex.Replace(firstPhaseText, @"(?s)\s*\/\/.+?\n|\/\*.*?\*\/\s*|\t", string.Empty);
            richTextBox1.Text = secondPhaseText;
            richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines.Where(emptyLine => emptyLine.Length > 0).ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

Код успешно удаляет многострочные комментарии, НО только когда есть конечный тег. Если стоит только начальный тег, то ничего не удаляется, что плохо ведь весь код после него считается комментарием.
Мне же нужно чтобы после /* удалялось всё если нету конечного тега. Скажите, каким образом можно это сделать?

Comment: А что будет с таким кодом? `Console.WriteLine("// привет");`? Вы вообще с каким именно кодом работаете? C#?

Comment: @aepot часть после // сотрётся, однако в анализируемом метода с таким текстом нету.  сам код из текстового файла- простой процесс определения чётности с помощью switch case, написанный на c++

Comment: С++? `gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E D:\3.txt` https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394040/12888024 или посмотрите там же другие способы, вроде даже регулярки есть

Comment: @aepot извините но код на С++ из файла нужен только для анализа, сам анализ и удаления комментариев происходит на C#. может я неправильно выразился